# $_FILES is empty after uploading more than 2 files with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

When uploading one or two images they exist in $_FILES but when there are more files, $_FILES is empty even though I can see the images in the request payload. The images together don't exceed more than a few MBs.

In php.ini max_filesize is 64M and max_file_uploads is 20. It worked bofore and for a reason I don't remember I changed the php script and it broke.

The form:

```
<form id="new-post-form" name="new-post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <textarea name="new-post-text" id="new-post-text" placeholder="What's up?"></textarea>
    <div id="new-post-image-container">
        <input type="file" class="new-post-image" name="new-post-image[]" multiple>
    </div> 
    <input type="button" name="post-submit" class="post-submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

Ajax request:

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

$.ajax({
  xhr: function() {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    //Upload progress
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
      if(event.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = event.loaded / event.total;
        //do something with upload progress        
      }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
  },
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost/Traveler\'s Hut - Cijeli/public/new_post.php',
  data: formData,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  beforeSend: function() {
  },
  success: function(response) {
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
  }
});
```

`var_dump($_FILES)` returns array size 0.

Comment: And what happens with `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: `It worked bofore and for a reason I don't remember I changed the php script and it broke.` Use version control like git and this will never happen again

Comment: @meda I learned the lesson just now.

Comment: @N.B. var_dump($_POST) also returns array size 0.

Comment: Don't use the JavaScript method for testing then. Also better look into `$_SERVER`, which provides more conclusive answers than an empty `$_POST`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in php.ini, post_max_size was set to 3M which was not enough for what I was trying to upload.